# Manipulate Form Controls at Record Level

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a continuous form that is bound to a table. Beside each record of my form I have an "Edit" button. I want to know if I can manipulate the form controls at record level, meaning:

when user clicks "Edit" button, the locked property of the current row of record is set to false and only to the current row

when user clicks "Edit" button, two more "Save" and "Cancel" buttons' visibilities are set to true and displayed at the end of the current row of record

Can I achieve this programmatically in vba?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate properties for a control in a continuos form affect to all the rows. But... you can use conditional format: For example, for Save button, you can set the enabled property depending on the Dirty form property.

Comment: Thanks. can you be more specific on the conditional format? I am trying to display the save button in response to the onclick event of my edit button. How does the dirty form property come into play here?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that buttons don't support conditional format (At least in Access 2003) The Dirty property is true if you have pending changes in the current report, so, theorically, you can set the enable property of a control depending on the state of the record

Comment: Why don't move the buttons to the header or footer area?
You can control the current row with the Form_Current event